# In SSIS, Data Flow connection takes a lot of time

Tags: ssis

I'm new to SSIS...
I upgraded a package (from 2008 to 2010 Visual studios) that connects to a flat file and dumps the data into a new table.
I get about 25 files every 5 minutes.
The problem is, in the package, it **takes more than 15 secs to connect to one single file** but the transfer is fast. Since it is this slow, there are alot of files left unprocessed.
My question is **how do I make it faster**?

I thought maybe up-gradation was an issue, so I made a completely new package. Then I tried to connect just two databases, even there the connection time is same.

Comment: How can you tell the connection time to a file?  Are you talking about how long it takes before you start seeing rows in the buffer in debug mode?  Is there anything else in the dataflow, i.e. a lookup, or is it just a flat file source and oledb destination?

Comment: When I run the package, it takes alot of time to enter into Data Flow in the debug mode. There is no lookup, theres just flat file src and oledb destination. If you require any more information ask me... I have no idea how much information is enough in this case! Gotta solve this problem asap! :x

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing does not sound like a connection issue, but more the beginning of the file being read and loaded into the buffer.  Things to consider would be:

- location of the file (network IO) - keep it local to the SSIS service if possible or copy it to the SSIS server before running it through a data flow
- the amount of memory available to SSIS
- the amount of memory allocated to the data flow

Some basic tuning steps would be:
 - Make sure the column sizes on the flat file connection are accurate (and not all set to string(500) or something like that).  This has a direct impact on how many rows will be processed at a time
 - Increase the DefaultMaxBufferRows and DefaultBufferSize in the data flow to increase the number of rows for each buffer
 - Make sure that your oledb destination is set to fast load.  If you are loading a heap, make sure tablock is on.  If you are loading a clustered index and there are multiple flows that will update the same table, make sure tablock is not on, or you will block yourself.  In this case, I would consider re-architecting the approach to sequential loading or using a multifile source.